# Docker container using only one CPU core

Tags: python, docker

I have a Docker container built on the `ubuntu:latest` base image that contains some python scripts. One of them does OCR on text and I've noticed the script it ~2-3x slower when I run it from docker compared to running it on local. Looking at resource usage when the script it running, it looks like it can detect 12 cores available for use but the container is only using one container at 100 % and the rest remain idle. When running it locally, it looks like all cores are working.

I also tried to run it with `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, but the container will always cap at 100 % and not use more than 1 CPU core.

I've found a lot of information about how to limit resources, but there is nothing that would force usage of resources. I also have tried an image based on the `python:3.10` image, but the same slowness and issue persists. That image is built on `debian bullseye`.

Per recommendation ran `lscpu` inside the container and got the following:

```
root@22b8b40396d5:/code# lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  12
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               158
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  6
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            10
    BogoMIPS:            7391.99
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb r
                         dtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 mo
                         vbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow
                          vnmi ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 x
                         saves flush_l1d arch_capabilities
```

[image: Image of utilization]

Comment: hey @qoob, have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: I have not - I recently upgraded my PC to a AMD Ryzen 9 7950X and the issue is the same, now with just more available cores that aren't used.

Answer (score 1):

To specify the number of available CPUs for your container, you can use "--cpus" flag like this:

```
docker run -it --cpus="12" ubuntu /bin/bash
```

You can read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#cpu).

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work. To be specific I tried `docker run --name my-container --env-file ./.env --cpus 12 --cpuset-cpus 0-11 my-image`. As I understand it `--cpus` is one of the ways you can use to limit resources, but it won't make a container use more of them.

Comment: Can you try running `lscpu` to see the number of CPUs available in your container?  `top` or `htop` should give you similar information.

Comment: You have to narrow down if it's a problem with the `docker run` command, or something else.

Comment: From the image you shared, I suspected it was a problem with `docker run`.

Comment: I've updated the post to show what `lscpu` returned. Basically it shows 12 CPUs available. This is the case even if I do the `docker run` command without any of the `cpus` flags.

Comment: So we need to look further into the script running OCR. If you are using Tesseract, you can specify the number of threads with the OMP_THREAD_LIMIT environment variable. Can you give that a try?

Comment: The script uses the exact same code in docker and on the host, on the same machine. The only difference is that one machine is windows 11 with python 3.11 and the other Ubuntu 22.04 in docker with python 3.10.4. Tesseract and pymupdf versions are the same